# Execute a command inside a particular directory using os/exec in golng

Tags: go

I want to run a command inside a particular directory.So here are 2 ways to do it.

```
command := exec.Command("echo *tar.gz | xargs -n1 tar zxf") 
command.Dir = pathFinal 
cmdErr := command.Run()
```

This is not working for me on the otherhand,

```
command := "cd "+pathFinal+"; "+"echo *tar.gz | xargs -n1 tar zxf" 
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", command) 
cmdErr := command.Run()
```

This is working. 
I want to implement it the first way. I don't know why it is not working
Second one throws an error

Failed to untar file: exec: "echo *tar.gz | xargs -n1 tar zxf": executable file not found in $PATH
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to Command specifies the executable to run. To run a shell pipe expression, execute a shell:

```
command := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", "echo *tar.gz | xargs -n1 tar zxf") 
command.Dir = pathFinal 
cmdErr := command.Run()
```